# С помощью рекурсии посчитать количество одинаковых элементов в листе и собрать это в словаре

Tags: python, list, рекурсия, словари

Помогите реализовать следующую функцию:

> ```
> def count(data: list, pos=None, result: dict = None) -> dict:
>     """
>     You are given a list of strings and lists, which may also contain strings and lists etc. Your job is to
>     collect these strings into a dict, where key would be the string and value the amount of occurrences of that string
>     in these lists.
>
>     :param data: given list of lists
>     :param pos: figure out how to use it
>     :param result: figure out how to use it
>     :return: dict of given symbols and their count
>     """
> ```

Вывод примерно такой.

```
print(count([[], ["J", "*", "W", "f"], ["j", "g", "*"], ["j", "8", "5", "6", "*"], ["*", "*", "A", "8"]]))

# {'J': 1, '*': 5, 'W': 1, 'f': 1, 'j': 2, 'g': 1, '8': 2, '5': 1, '6': 1, 'A': 1}

print(count([[], [], [], [], ["h", "h", "m"], [], ["m", "m", "M", "m"]])) 

 # {'h': 2, 'm': 4, 'M': 1}

print(count([]))  

# {}

print(count([['a'], 'b', ['a', ['b']]]))  

# {'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Мои наброски:

```
if result is None and pos is None:
    result = {}
    pos = 0
if pos > len(data):
    return result
if isinstance(data[pos], str):
    return count_strings(data, pos + 1, result)
elif isinstance(data, list):
    return count_strings(data, 0, result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код:

```
def cnt_same(l: list, res=None) -> dict:
    if res is None:
        res = {}
    for i in l:
        if not type(i) == list:
            res[i] = res.get(i,0)+1
        else:
            cnt_same(i, res)
    return res
```

Проверка:

```
print(cnt_same([[], ["J", "*", "W", "f"], ["j", "g", "*"], ["j", "8", "5", "6", "*"], ["*", "*", "A", "8"]]))
#{'J': 1, '*': 5, 'W': 1, 'f': 1, 'j': 2, 'g': 1, '8': 2, '5': 1, '6': 1, 'A': 1}

print(cnt_same([['a'], 'b', ['a', ['b']]]))
#{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Третий метод [отсюда](https://djangocentral.com/nested-list-to-flat-list/) потому, что заявлен, как один из самых эффективных для больших списков:

```
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for li in [[[], ["J", "*", "W", "f"], ["j", "g", "*"], ["j", "8", "5", "6", "*"], ["*", "*", "A", "8"]],
           [[], [], [], [], ["h", "h", "m"], [], ["m", "m", "M", "m"]]]:
    c.update(chain.from_iterable(li))
    pprint(c)
    c.clear()
```

**Вывод:**

```
Counter({'*': 5,
         'j': 2,
         '8': 2,
         'f': 1,
         'W': 1,
         'A': 1,
         'g': 1,
         '6': 1,
         '5': 1,
         'J': 1})
Counter({'m': 4, 'h': 2, 'M': 1})
```

[Демо](https://rextester.com/ZXY69166).
Для вывода использован [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html) модуль.

Comment: В вопросе сказано "с помощью рекурсии".

Comment: мы здесь вузовские задачки решаем или пытаемся находить эффективные промышленные решения?

Comment: Мы здесь отвечаем на вопросы.